# What ever happened to deltree, and what's its replacement?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

In earlier versions of MS-DOS - I want to say version 7, but I could be wrong - there was a `deltree` command, which recursively deleted all subdirectories and files from a given path.

`deltree` no longer exists, but `del` didn't seem to inherit the ability to delete a tree. `del /s` deletes files, but not folders.

How to you easily (i.e., in one command) delete a tree from a batch file?

Comment: deltree was introduced in version 5.0 (I still remember the glee of being able to use it) - Man I feel old.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `rd` command has the `/s` switch to recursively remove sub-directories. You can combine it with the `/q` switch to forcibly delete a sub-directory (and its contents) without prompting as so

```
rd /s /q c:\foobar
```

What everybody is missing is that `rd` is *not* an exact replacement for `deltree` as seemingly ([almost](http://www.technofileonline.com/texts/bkdeltree98.html)) every page returned by Googling for `windows deltree` would have you believe. The `deltree` command worked for both directories **and files**, making it a single convenient, all-purpose deletion command. That is both of the following are valid:

```
deltree /y c:\foobar
deltree /y c:\baz.txt
```

However `rd` (not surprisingly) *only works for directories*. As such only the first of these commands is valid while the second gives and error and leaves the file un-deleted:

```
rd /s /q c:\foobar
rd /s /q c:\baz.txt
```

Further, the `del` command only works for files, not directories, so only the second command is valid while the first gives an error:

```
del /f /q c:\foobar
del /f /q c:\baz.txt
```

There is no built-in way to delete files and directories as could be done with `deltree`. Using `rd` and `del` individually is inconvenient at best because it requires distinguishing whether a file-system object (file-/folder-name) is a file or directory which is not always possible or practical.

You can copy the `deltree` command from a previous OS, however it will only work on 32-bit versions of Windows since it is a 16-bit DOS command (even in Windows 9x).

Another option is to create a batch-file that calls both `del` and `rd`; something like this:

```
::deltree.bat

@echo off
rd  %* 2> nul
del %* 2> nul
```

You would call it as so:

```
deltree.bat /s /q /f c:\foobar
deltree.bat /s /q /f c:\baz.txt
```

This calls both `rd` and `del`, passing in the arguments and redirecting the output to `nul` to avoid the error that one of them will invariably emit.

You will probably want to customize the behavior to accomodate or simplify parameters or allow error messages, but even so, it is not ideal and not a direct replacement for `deltree`.

An alternative is to get a third-party tool, though finding one is a real exercise in search-query-crafting.

Comment: @TobyAllen, “rm”? Did you mean *rd*? If so, then you need to re-read the help text; it says *Removes all directories and files **in the specified directory** in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory tree.* Like I said, it does not delete files. If you use it as so: `rd /s foobar.txt`, it will prompt you if you are sure, and if you say yes (or use the `/q` switch), then it gives the error `The directory name is invalid.`

Comment: You actually can remove everything under a directory (including its subdirectories) with `RMDIR /S`, so to say there's no way to delete both files and folders in one blow is actually incorrect.

Comment: @vapcguy, `rd /s` only applies to the *directory, not the files inside it*. In order to delete the files in it, you have to use `rd` on the directory itself. For example, you can't say `rd c:\target\foobar.txt`, you'd have to use `rd /s c:\target`, but you may not want to delete the directory itself, just its contents. `deltree` could do that, but `rd /s` cannot, `rd /s` also deletes the directory itself.

Comment: Notice I said `RMDIR /S`- not `rd /s`. But even with `rd`, if the directory is gone, how are the files not removed? Even if they weren't, the files are effectively orphaned & should be garbage collected by the system. And even if that didn't happen, it certainly does if you re-create the directory-you don't magically get a list of your files, again. Pointers are essentially removed. So are you saying you just never get that space back, because you are never able to delete those files, again, if you use `rd /s`? Not sure I'd believe that-that'd be a terrible bug. Point is to delete files & dir.

Comment: If you create a directory in your "Documents" folder called "test", create a test text document there in Windows, then close the Explorer window, go to a command line, `cd Documents`, `rd /s test`, your directory and your text file will be removed. `rmdir /s test` works, too. You NEVER try to use `rd /s C:\Users\me\Documents\test\test.txt`- that would be absolutely stupid. But you CAN and SHOULD use the command on the directory, just not on the file name. But by removing the directory you can remove the files.

Comment: `RMDIR /S- not rd /s` I'm not sure what you're saying. Is the dash supposed to be part of the switch? Is the switch case-sensitive in Windows 10? (It's not in Windows 7). `But even with rd, if the directory is gone, how are the files not removed?` That's if you remove the parent directory itself (which isn't always what you want), but even then, the `rd` command doesn't actually work on the files directly. `But you CAN and SHOULD use the command on the directory` Again, you don't always want to remove the directory itself, `deltree` would let you remove only its contents, but `rd` doesn't. :-\

Comment: Jeez, man, no-the hyphen was just punctuation. Did you even look at my next response after that? Did I use a hyphen there? No. No, it's not case-sensitive-did that for emphasis. "Parent directory"? No. It's if you remove **THE** directory that's holding the files. You don't have to do `rd /s C:\Documents` to remove something at `C:\Documents\test`. You can just do `rd /s C:\Documents\test` & that removes a document at `C:\Documents\test\test.txt`. This isn't rocket science. Test & see. Yes, there's times you only want to delete a file, `del` for that-but doubt that's what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: `Deltree` isn't for deleting just the contents of folders. It deletes the folders, too. That's why it has `tree` in the name. `Del` is for deleting individual files.

Comment: I didn't say it's *only* for deleting the contents, I said that's something you can do with it which you can't do anymore with built-in commands.

Comment: Except you said that `rd` doesn't replace `deltree`.  And you're trying to say *"deleting the contents... [is] something you can't do anymore with built-in commands"*. I just demonstrated how that isn't true. `rd /s` and `rmdir /s` and `deltree` are all built-in commands and *they do delete the contents*. Of course that's not the only thing they do - they delete the folders, too. But it seemed like you wanted to say the contents wouldn't be removed by deleting the folder. They are.

Comment: Why is this so difficult? Deleting just the contents *isn't* something that you can do with built-in commands because `deltree` was never ported to Windows and `rd /s` doesn't delete only the contents, it removes the folder itself. I never said the contents wouldn't be removed, I said `rd` doesn't work directly on files. This is one of the reasons I left the SE network. Arguing over nothing. ¬_¬

Comment: No one would be trying to delete *just the contents* of a folder, if they are using a command that **deletes a folder**. That's silly. `deltree` was never a command to delete *just the contents* of a folder without taking out the folder, too & YES-it WAS active on Windows MS-DOS, at least in Win98. They replaced it with `rmdir`. Of course `rd /s` deletes the folder - it literally stands for "remove directory". If you say *rd doesn't work directly on files*, you're going to confuse people. Emphasize *directly*. But even that's unnecessary to point out, since it WILL remove the files.

Comment: No  it was not replaced, as rd (rmdir) existed  as  it does now as an internal shell command, while  deltree was an external one. The one thing that is not easy to do now is to delete all contents of, which could be done with deltree but not with ch could be done with deltree but not with rmdir

Answer (score 46):

It was replaced with the commands: RMDIR or RD

Delete all subdirectories with /S

Use it quietly with the /Q

Example:

```
RMDIR /S /Q Folder2Delete
RD /S /Q Folder2Delete
```

Documentation:

- [DELTREE at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltree)
- [RMDIR at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rmdir)
- [RMDIR at Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx)

Comment: "RMDIR /S /Q .\"  effectively wipes the current directory and everything under it.  Yes, it complains about not being able to delete the current directory, which can be useful.  Just make sure you're in the correct directory when running it! :)

Answer (score 10):

Feeling nostalgic, I wrote my own deltree.exe. It works with both directories and files, and uses SHFileOperation() for speed.

https://github.com/ai7/toolbox/tree/master/deltree

```
deltree v1.01 [Mar 27 2015, 16:31:02] (gcc 4.9.1)

Usage: deltree [options] <path> ...

Options:
  -y    yes, suppresses prompting for confirmation
  -s    silent, do not display any progress dialog
  -n    do nothing, simulate the operation
  -f    force, no prompting/silent (for rm compatibility)
  -r    ignored (for rm compatibility)

Delete directories and all the subdirectories and files in it.
```

It takes wildcards and you can use it like unix rm:

```
deltree -rf *
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'd like to note that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationa says that "This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by IFileOperation." Don't know that it matters, though!

Answer (score 8):

```
rmdir /s /q directory
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, you can use Powershell to do the same task:

```
powershell -Command "Remove-Item 'PathToMyDirectory\*' -Recurse -Force"
```

Comment: Unfortunately PowerShell is bloated and slow. :-\ I hate it when companies try to force users to "upgrade" to their latest junk. 

Comment: I feel like this answer is an accidental advertisement for CMD over PowerShell: `rd /s /q "dir"` is much shorter to type and easier to read. Still nice to have the native answer for PS available though!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ help rd
Removes (deletes) a directory.

RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

    /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
            in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
            tree.

    /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually RMDIR and RD commands in modern Windows operating system merge both the commands RD and Deltree of Win 98 in a single command. It's an internal command that's why you won't find any RD.exe and RMDIR.exe.

By typing this "RD /?" in cmd without double qoutes you'll get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

to delete a directory and all it's contents recursively

```
rd /s MY_DOOMED_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
cd (your directory here)
del *.* /f /s /q
```

Comment: Could you please add a brief explanation for the flags? That will make this answer even more valuable. Thanks.

Comment: This has been mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345791/711006) already.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files and subdirectories

```
cd /d Directory && rd /s /q .\
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be a duplicate of other answers (some are 10 years old). I can't see any more or better explanations or any other advantage

Comment: @jeb, actually it's not. It's slightly different, and that slight difference is crucial and makes it superior. 

Answer (score 0):

Others have already posted excellent answers. I regularly use `rd /s /q` in a command prompt with a `for` loop to delete directories under the current one: `for /d %d in (*) do rd /s /q "%d"` (where `*` can be replaced with names instead, e.g. `(dir1 dir2 dirX)`