# How to delete all files and folders in a folder by cmd call

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use Windows.

I want to delete all files and folders in a folder by system call.

I may call like that:

```
>rd /s /q c:\destination
>md c:\destination
```

Do you know an easier way?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/173859/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subfolders-in-a-given-folder-via-the-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What ever happened to deltree, and what's its replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338895/what-ever-happened-to-deltree-and-whats-its-replacement)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

No, I don't know one.

If you want to retain the original directory for some reason (ACLs, &c.), and instead really want to empty it, then you can do the following:

```
del /q destination\*
for /d %x in (destination\*) do @rd /s /q "%x"
```

This first removes all files from the directory, and then recursively removes all nested directories, but overall keeping the top-level directory as it is (except for its contents).

Note that within a batch file you need to double the `%` within the `for` loop:

```
del /q destination\*
for /d %%x in (destination\*) do @rd /s /q "%%x"
```

Comment: i was able to do this without a batch file. use the && to concat the two operations

Comment: I am a complete windows-shell noob:  how do i set the destination to a path with this example?

Comment: You replace the word `destination` by the path, possibly using quotes around the whole thing if necessary.

Comment: This answer makes me sad, _because_ it is the best answer

Comment: The first line is useless. The second will delete both folders and files.

Comment: @stenci: `rd`, `rmdir`: *Removes (deletes) a directory.* The first line removes all (top-level) files from the directory to empty. The second line will remove all directories (recursively) from the directory to empty. Note that `rd` will not remove files (unless beneath a directory to remove), and `for /d` explicitly only iterates over directories, too. I actually *thought* my answer was clear and straightforward enough, but apparently not.

Comment: Did you test it? I just tested it: the first line is useless. `rd /s /q "path"` deletes both files and folders

Comment: @stenci: The second line can _only_ delete the given directory. It does so recursively, indeed, but it _cannot_ delete a file. Therefore, to remove everything inside a directory you have to remove all files, and all directories. Note that this is _not_ about deleting a single directory and everything within. It's about deleting everything within and _keeping_ the parent directory.

Comment: You are right. In my case it is useless because the folder contains only sub-folders with sub-sub-folders and files, and I didn't understand the first line because the second one does delete my files.

Comment: This works but I had to do the `for /d %p in (*) do @rd /s /q "%p"` twice! The first time some directories were reported to be not empty. Windows must be recursing improperly. Perhaps this a flawed multi-thread implementation.

Comment: `If you want to retain the original directory for some reason` "For some reason"?  You mean like deleting the *contents* of `%temp%` but not the folder itself? Is that a reason?

Comment: Beware, don't set the destination as '/' like I just did. This will try to delete C:\... I thought it would delete everything from the current working directory.

Answer (score 42):

`del c:\destination\*.* /s /q` worked for me.  I hope that works for you as well.

Comment: Deletes all the files but not the folders.

Comment: What worked for me was navigate to the folder. (shift right click, select open cmd prompt here) then `del *.*`

Comment: example for relative path `del "../../server/front-end\*.*"`

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch, that's not very scriptable.

Comment: The `*.*` mask used will skip files that do not have an extension. For example `makefile`. Mask must be used `*`.

Answer (score 34):

I think the easiest way to do it is:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\FolderToDelete\"
```

The last "" in the path is the important part.

This deletes the folder itself. To retain, add `mkdir "C:\FolderToDelete\"` to your script.

Comment: This also deletes the folder itself.

Comment: Does this works recursively what is the path it too long?

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, since it deletes the folders & files recursively

Comment: combining this with `mkdir C:\FolderToNotToDelete` was enough for me :)

Comment: This can be problematic if your parent folder (which gets deleted this way) holds some important permissions, which you now need to recreate...

Answer (score 18):

Yes! Use Powershell:

```
powershell -Command "Remove-Item 'c:\destination\*' -Recurse -Force"
```

Answer (score 14):

If the subfolder names may contain spaces you need to surround them in escaped quotes. The following example shows this for commands used in a batch file.

```
set targetdir=c:\example
del /q %targetdir%\*
for /d %%x in (%targetdir%\*) do @rd /s /q ^"%%x^"
```

Answer (score 9):

To delete file:

```
del PATH_TO_FILE
```

To delete folder with all files in it:

```
rmdir /s /q PATH_TO_FOLDER
```

To delete all files from specific folder (not deleting folder itself) is a little bit complicated. `del /s *.*` cannot delete folders, but removes files from all subfolder. So two commands are needed:

```
del /q PATH_TO_FOLDER\*.*
for /d %i in (PATH_TO_FOLDER\*.*) do @rmdir /s /q "%i"
```

You can create a script to delete whatever you want (folder or file) like this `mydel.bat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %0 path
    exit /b 1
)

:: check whether it is folder or file
set ISDIR=0
set ATTR=%~a1
set DIRATTR=%ATTR:~0,1%
if /i "%DIRATTR%"=="d" set ISDIR=1

:: Delete folder or file
if %ISDIR%==1 (rmdir /s /q "%~1") else (del "%~1")
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Few example of usage:

```
mydel.bat "path\to\folder with spaces"
mydel.bat path\to\file_or_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy one-line option is to create an empty directory somewhere on your file system, and then use `ROBOCOPY` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) with the `/MIR` switch to remove all files and subfolders.  By default, robocopy does not copy security, so the ACLs in your root folder should remain intact.

Also probably want to set a value for the retry switch, `/r`, because the default number of retries is 1 million.

```
robocopy "C:\DoNotDelete_UsedByScripts\EmptyFolder" "c:\temp\MyDirectoryToEmpty" /MIR /r:3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an index folder with 33 folders that needed all the files and subfolders removed in them.  I opened a command line in the index folder and then used these commands:

```
for /d in (*) do rd /s /q "%a" & (
md "%a")
```

I separated them into two lines (hit enter after first line, and when asked for more add second line) because if entered on a single line this may not work.  This command will erase each directory and then create a new one which is empty, thus removing all files and subflolders in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the parent directory

## Line1 pushd "Parent Directory"

Delete the sub folders

## Line2 rd /s /q . 2>nul

https://superuser.com/questions/173859/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subfolders-in-a-given-folder-via-the-command-prompt

Comment: If you use `pushd` you have to use `popd` too. Unfortunately, `popd` does not work when you delete the directory. So, you have to do `cd` instead of `pushd`.

Answer (score 0):

It takes 2 simple steps.  [/q means quiet, /f means forced, /s means subdir]

1. Empty out the directory to remove

   ```
   del *.* /f/s/q
   ```
2. Remove the directory

   ```
   cd ..
   rmdir dir_name /q/s
   ```

[image: See picture]

Comment: what if you just want to remove the contents and not the entire directory?

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will search all MyFolder under root dir and delete all folders named MyFolder

```
for /d /r "C:\Users\test" %%a in (MyFolder\) do if exist "%%a" rmdir /s /q "%%a"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
del .\*
```

This Command delete all files & folders from current navigation in your command line.