# Remove only files and sub folders from a directory through command prompt

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, del

I have a folder named `Test` in `C:\Test` path. There are multiple files and folders in this `Test` folder. Now I want to remove all the contents with in the `Test` Folder and not delete the `Test` folder itself.

I have been trying these commands, but it only deletes the files and not folders.

```
del C:\Test\* 
del C:\Test\*.*
```

I want a single command to delete both files and sub folders from `Test`.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502913/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-by-cmd-call >rd /s /q c:\destination
>md c:\destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command which has to be used.

```
CD "C:/Test" && FOR /D %i IN ("*") DO RD /S /Q "%i" && DEL /Q *.*
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with a single command, but with a single command line.

I would do this:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Test" && rd /S /Q "C:\Test"
```

This first changes into the destination root directory. The [`&&` operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) lets the following command execute only when the preceding one succeeded. Then the directory and all its contents is attempted to be deleted; for the contents it works fine, but for the root itself, the error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` because of the preceding `cd` command. This error message (and also others) can be suppressed by appending `2> nul` to the `rd` command:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Test" && rd /S /Q "C:\Test" 2> nul
```

If you want the original working directory to be restored, use `pushd`/`popd` rather than `cd`:

```cmd
pushd "C:\Test" && (rd /S /Q "C:\Test" 2> nul & popd)
```

The advantage of this method over deletion and recreation (like `rd /S /Q "C:\test" && md "C:\Test"`) is that the attributes, the owner and the security settings of the root directory are not lost.

---

Alternatively, you could do the following, which is more complicated but avoids suppression of errors:

```cmd
del /S /Q "C:\Test\*.*" & for /D %%D in ("C:\Test\*") do @rm /S /Q "%%~D"
```

This first deletes all files that reside in the root directory, then it loops through all immediate sub-directories and deletes one after another. The root directory itself is never touched.