# How to delete all file and folders with msbuild

Tags: msbuild

How can I delete all files and folders from a given path?

I tried this, but I'm unable to select the directories.

```
<Target Name="CleanSource" Condition="$(path)!=''">

    <Message Text="path=$(path)"/>

    <ItemGroup>
      <fileToDelete Include="$(path)\**\*.*" />
      <directoryToDelete Include="$(path)\**\" /><!these doest not select any directory at all-->     
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="file to delete:@(fileToDelete)"/>
    <Message Text="directory to delete:@(directoryToDelete)"/>

    <Delete Files="@(fileToDelete)" />
    <Message Text="file effectively deleted:@(DeletedFiles)"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(directoryToDelete)" />
    <Message Text="Directory effectively deleted:@(RemovedDirectories)"/>

</Target>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Msbuild - how to delete folder contents but not folder itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109785/msbuild-how-to-delete-folder-contents-but-not-folder-itself)

Answer (score -22, accepted):

Finally I did use powershell wich is much more fast:

```
<exec>
 <executable>powershell.exe</executable>
 <buildArgs><![CDATA[-command "& {if( [System.IO.Directory]::Exists($pwd) ){dir $pwd | ri -recurse
    -force}}"]]></buildArgs>
</exec>
```

Comment: Using Powershell is not what was expected here.

Comment: This is not really deleting the folder "with msbuild", as the original question was phrased.

Comment: This fulfills an interesting criteria: it allows you to add a `-Force` flag

Comment: @Izzy: OP simply accepted own solution regardless of any practical answers provided.

Answer (score 77):

The [RemoveDir task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyfz6ddb.aspx) removes the specified directories and all of its files and subdirectories. You don't have to remove the files and subdirectories first. Just pass the directory name to RemoveDir.

```
   <ItemGroup>
        <DirsToClean Include="work" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="CleanWork">
        <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToClean)" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: Thx, but the param I get is a path and i just want all directory under these path to be deleted. Not the files in the root of that path.

Comment: Your original question says "delete all file and folders from a given path". If your requirement is different you should state that in the question. To only delete the folders from a directory, leaving the files, you will need a custom task. If your naming scheme is such that you could create an ItemGroup of the folder names, then you could pass that ItemGroup to RemoveDir to delete them.

Comment: I don't want to delete the folder, just the contents of the folder.

Answer (score 16):

While there are ways to construct this using just MSBuild, I'd highly recommend the MSBuild Extension pack.

<strike>http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/</strike> *[has been moved]*
[GitHub: MSBuildExtensionPack](http://mikefourie.github.io/MSBuildExtensionPack/)

Using the pack, you get a RemoveContent task that does exactly what you are needing.  Once you install, you'd just do something like:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Folder
   TaskAction="RemoveContent" Path="$(PathtoEmpty)"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm arriving to this conversation a little late, but I found the easiest way to accomplish this was to use the `Exec` task to execute the batch command given by lain in response to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965787/cmd-delete-files-subfolders-in-a-specific-directory) (with minor edits by yours truly):

```
<Exec Command="FOR /D %%p IN (&quot;$(path)*.*&quot;) DO rmdir &quot;%%p&quot; /s /q" />
```

Comment: Your solution deletes the main folder too.

Comment: This is pretty hacky as it is not platform independent any longer.