# How to delete folder in the folder?

Tags: batch-file

How to delete files and folders in the folder?

Eg. "cat" folder. In the folder existing (3 folders and 5 mp3s and 4 docxs)files.
       I delete with this codes:

```
       del /f /s /q c:\cat


       rd /s /q c:\cat
```

del.....   it delete mp3, docx but not del 3 folders. It delete files in the 3 folder.it not del 3 folders.

rd......   it delete "cat" folder, I don't del "cat" folder. I want is to delete files and folders in the "cat" folder.

Comment: This works well, if you can use a batch file:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462274/1863970

Answer (score 2):

```
 for /d %%a in (c:\cat\*) do echo rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

---

```
Removes (deletes) a directory.
```

RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

```
/S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
        in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
        tree.

/Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rd /s /q c:\cat
md c:\cat
```

(as you don't need no files or folders inside you can delete the folder and re-create it)

Looking for a better way...**EDIT:**(I think is not possible without listing items)

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b  "c:\cat"') do ( 
  rd /s /q "%~a" >nul 2>&1||del /q /f "%~a" >nul 2>&1
)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank! But i think it is merry-go-round.(create a new folder)

Comment: Do you have another way? Thank for help!

Comment: I've edited the post.In brief I thing it's not possible without listing the folder items (here it is done with dir command). You can also try Endoro's way.In all cases it requires more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
( pushd "c:\cat" && rmdir . /s /q ) & popd
```

Change to the desired directory.

If that do work, then remove current directory. This will delete all inside the current directory, but, as the current directory is in use, it can't be deleted.

Once finished, return to previous directory