# Batch File Deleting Contents But Leaving Folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm running a batch file to delete the contents (and sub-folders) of a temp directory based on the subfolder names existing in deletedirs.txt

```
FOR /F %%i IN (C:\deletedirs.txt) DO del "C:\temppurge\*" rmdir /s /q "C:\temppurge\"%%i
```

Deletes the contents of the sub-folders in the temppurge directory but leaves the sub-folders themselves in tact.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not the solution, but: you must place an `&` in between two concatenated commands as you have: `del ... & rmdir ...`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/. See my answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file. Delete all files and folders in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/batch-file-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch file (shell script).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
if {%1}=={} goto :HELP
if {%1}=={/?} goto :HELP
goto :START

:HELP
echo Usage: %~n0 directory-name
echo.
echo Empties the contents of the specified directory,
echo WITHOUT CONFIRMATION. USE EXTREME CAUTION!
goto :DONE

:START
pushd %1 || goto :DONE
rd /q /s . 2> NUL
popd

:DONE
endlocal
```