# Batch scripting: exclude files from set

Tags: batch-file

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
for %%i not in (*.xml *.doc) do ....
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. Is there a way I can do something similar in a batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *^|findstr /live ".bat .txt"') do ...
```

***Addendum***

This solution will slow down in a non-linear fashion if the directory listing becomes huge. This is unlikely to be a problem with a single directory, but can easily become a problem if the DIR /S option is used. The solution can be restored to having a linear response time with respect to listing size by using temp files.

```
set temp1="%temp%\dirExclude1_%random%.txt"
set temp2="%temp%\dirExclude2_%random%.txt"
>%temp1% dir /s /b /a-d *
>%temp2% findstr /live ".bat .txt" %temp1%
for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%i in (%temp2%) do ...
del %temp1%
del %temp2%
```

This is a general limitation with Windows pipes. They become very inefficient with large amounts of data. It is always much faster to use temp files instead of a pipe when dealing with large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes, that definitely worked, and it's much simpler than the proposed alternatives! But how does it work? I've figured out most of it but the *^| is new to me.

Comment: If you have a lot of files and speed matters, Aacini's solution is probably faster (I did not measure, but shelling out is expensive)

Comment: @Anders - I've done the test, and the Aacini solution was actually 2.5 times SLOWER. Also the Aacini solution fails with `=` or `!` in the file name. My solution will slow down disproportionally if the dir size is HUGE, but that can be fixed by redirecting the DIR to a tempFile1, using FINDSTR to create tempFile2, and then using tempFile2 in the FOR IN clause instead of the piped command. But this optimization should only be needed in extraordinary circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Build a list of files to exclude
set exclude=
for %%i in (*.xml *.doc) do set "exclude=!exclude!%%i*"
rem Process all but excluded files
for %%i in (*.*) do (
   if "!exclude!" equ "!exclude:%%i*=!" echo Process this one: %%i
)
```

Comment: 1) I believe you intended `"!exclude:.%%i.=!"` in your IF statement. 2) Will not work properly if file name contains `=`. 3) Problem if both `"a.txt"` and `"a.txt.doc"` exist - easily solved by using `*` as a delimiter instead of `.` since `*` cannot exist in file name or path.

Comment: My mistake, should use `?` instead of `*` or `.`. Initialize `set exclude=?` and in IF use `!exclude:?%%i?=!`. Another alternative is to use `:` as delimiter, but that could cause problems if FOR /R option is used with full path in `%%i`.

Comment: This solution will also fail if a file name contains `!` because delayed expansion is enabled. Fixing this limitation will slow it down considerably. There is no good, practical way to allow for `=` in the file name with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cls
set folder=C:\Users\MARKETING 1\Desktop\CONDIVISA
cd /d "%folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if not "%%i"=="FILE SALVATI QUI VERRANNO CANCELLATI AUTOMATICAMENTE OGNI SABATO.txt" (
        if exist "%%i" (
            if /i "%%~ai"=="d" (
                rmdir "%%i" /s/q
            ) else (
                del "%%i" /q
            )
        )
    )
)
attrib +r "FILE SALVATI QUI VERRANNO CANCELLATI AUTOMATICAMENTE OGNI SABATO.txt"
del /q *.*
rd /s /q .
attrib -r "FILE SALVATI QUI VERRANNO CANCELLATI AUTOMATICAMENTE OGNI SABATO.txt"
```

That is a batch file which deletes all files and subfolders excluding the file named:

```
FILE SALVATI QUI VERRANNO CANCELLATI AUTOMATICAMENTE OGNI SABATO.txt
```

Comment: The __FOR__ loop ignores directories and files with hidden attribute set and does not delete files with read-only attribute set. The command `del /q *.*` ignores also files with hidden attribute set and does not delete files with read-only attribute set. The command `rd /s /q .` deletes all directories and files including the file which should not be deleted at all. I recommend to look on [Batch delete all files and directories except specified file and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57110498/3074564) how to code the deletion of all files and directories with exceptions correct.

Comment: This code is an unnecessary long version of [How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656521/3074564) because of `cd /d "%folder%"` and `rd /s /q .` with the disadvantage on deleting everything in current folder whatever the current folder is if the `cd` command failed to change the current directory because of the directory assigned to the environment variable does not exist at all. It is a very dangerous batch file for that reason and is definitely not a solution for the task to delete nearly all files.