# Visual Studio 2015 crashes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Visual studio that won't be repaired...**
Everytime I want to compile an app on vs 2015 - it crashes. Even if I want to compile the main function or write somthing to it, there appears a window, which says

> *Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working*

It goes same on 2013 Express version.
I have a clue why it won't work: when I open Team Explorer, an error appears:

> Page '3185ed96-1cbd-4381-a439-636973542e50' not found.

I tried everything I have found in the internet and trust me - nothing worked.
I also tried some command prompt commands:

```
devenv.exe/ debug  
devenv.exe/ resetsettings  
devenv.exe/ instalvstemplates  
devenv.exe/ resetskippings  
devenv.exe/ resetuserdata  
devenv.exe/ setup  
devenv.exe/ safemode
```

**Debug mode gave me some info about the error:**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The service '`Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsUIThreadInvokerPrivate`' must be installed for this feature to work.  Ensure that this service is available. HRESULT = 0x80004002

An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml".

```
Exception details:
System.ArgumentException: Parametr is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, UInt32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

**But still nothing I was able to find has worked.**

I reinstalled VS and repaired it - still nothing.
Then I have downloaded some .dlls, microsoft visual c++ redistributable packages and used Ccleaner to clean registry.
I think it's a very strange error; if you could advise me on a fix please?

Comment: Does this happen on a minimal "hello world" app?  Sounds odd.  Possibly a problem with the OS itself, or malware.  Are you fully service packed and up to date, virus checker, etc?

Comment: Have you tried to report it back to Microsoft? It's their product.

Comment: Yes, I have reported it to Microsoft and yes, I am fully serviced, but I'll check again. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried starting Visual Studio in SafeMode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the post, I have started VS with safemode.

Comment: try to update device driver (Intel HD Graphics) or Run with graphic driver if u got switch based.

Comment: This has just started happening for me.  When I double click a class name in the C# code file it hangs then reports it has stopped working.  Absolutely fuming.  Cant see ActivityLog.xml being updated.

Comment: `devenv.exe/ debug ` devenv.exe does not have /debug command line switch. How you tried this switch ?

Comment: I have worked on many versions of Visual Studio since the beginning of .NET and all of them have been very unstable compared to today's standard.  I have also worked with Android Studio, Xamarin Studio, Delphi RAD and have never experienced so much instability with any of them compared to Visual Studio.  Even Eclipse, which I find not that good, seem to be more stable.  I my self am trying to figure out why

Comment: This keeps happening to me. I tried removing all the extensions, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. I tried everything listed on this page. Finally as a last resort, yesterday I got a whole new computer from IT. It's still happening.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Uncheck [Tools->Options->Environment->Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance]

Uncheck [Use hardware graphics acceleration if available]

You can leave [Enable rich client visual experience] checked

I was having a lot of problems anywhere from random crashes, to crashing my Intel Graphics display driver, I turned it off and I have had no problems, it actually runs better. Maybe it will work for you

Comment: This worked for me.  I installed VS2015 Community edition and tried opening iSpy32 solution, but everything froze once it opened.  Working ok now.

Comment: This workaround worked. The error in event viewer contained:
System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat.get_InternalBitsPerPixel()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.GetClosestDUCEFormat(System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette)
   at  ...
So, clearly this was related to graphics presentation. This was the .net runtime exception, which was always accompanied with the Visual Studio (devenv.exe) exception. Very nice workaround indeed!

Comment: Tools->Options->General->Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance should be Tools->Options->Environment->General->Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance

Comment: Ty for this tip! My VS 2015 IDE would glitch out after a 60-90 mins of use (especially if I opened and closed it a few times). This fixed my issue!

Comment: I don't think this is solution to problem this is platform specific workaround that may or may not exist for particular PC. i think this problem still exist for me i need to install vs everyday before starting my working. its like hell. is there any other person having this problem. i am willing to create a new question for it to have detailed solutions that anyone used

Answer (score 19):

I was facing the same issue for team explorer.
First of all close all instances of visual studio and then try:

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

Run above command at the command prompt; typically something similar to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"

Comment: Good remedy for a variety of problems. Including my VS 2015 crashing after installing the latest SSDT. (why isn't this stuff documented on MS's troubleshooting/install pages)

Answer (score 5):

### Possible fix for these type errors:

try to update device driver (Intel HD Graphics) or Run with graphic driver if u got switch based or vice versa.

main executable is located

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Also if you are getting these type error on installation exe you can fix it the same way
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses WPF:
From [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/963021) link: "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) differs from prior application platforms on Windows in that it uses its own DirectX-based hardware-accelerated rendering pipeline, when available, to draw the contents of any WPF windows.  Prior application platforms were typically much less dependent on display driver quality because the bulk of their rendering was done in software rather than hardware."
So, it may conflict with the display driver causing it to stop if you don't have latest display driver or the latest .NET framework. Though there might be other reasons.

There is also a registry settings(regedit) which might help:
You can add a new DWORD(for 32-bit systems) or QWORD(for 64-bit) by going to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->Control->GraphicsDrivers]
and setting the name to "TdrDelay" and value to "8". Make sure the value's base is set to hexadecimal. TDR- Timeout Detection and Recovery.

If any of the above doesn't work. Try disabling any hardware accelerated rendering features in Visual Studio from [Tools->Options]. From your ActivityLog file, it seems that the exceptions are mostly in the graphics methods. So, my guess is it has to do with graphics rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Click on Tools menu > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > Next > "No, just reset settings, overwriting all current settings" > Next > Finish.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
i have faced problem of visual studio installation 
it stop before start installation and i just go to control panel > programs >Turn windows features on or of > just uncheck all the .NETframework versions and restart your machine and then start the installation 
this just how it works with me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try closing VS, deleting the `bin` directory then attempting to debug again – it has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I'm seeing similar behavior since today.
Every time I load our solution, VS2015 crashes and restarts.
Windows Event Log shows 'out of memory exception' but there's over 2GB free at the time of the crash. the faulting module is KERNELBASE.DLL

In case this helps anyone:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23915, time stamp: 0x59b94abb
```

I'm suspecting a windows update, as none of my colleagues have this problem and unfortunately I'm that nerd who always installs his updates ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I found this SOF article  and tried everything listed.

And I found a new caveat to this voodoo.

Mine falls under the "the dumbest reason ever" category.

My temp folder was "full".  So I did a disk clean up, and that deleted the FILES.  However, I had a large amount of subfolders in my temp folder and while they were empty, the folders themselves were causing GetTempFile functions to fail.

So when I ran

> "C:\blah\blah\blah\IDE\devenv.exe" /log

the log entries in ActivityLog.xml were showing something like this:

```
System.IO.IOException: The file exists.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMargin.get_RightArrowCursor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMarginProvider.CreateMargin(IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost, IWpfTextViewMargin containerMargin)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.ContainerMargin.&lt;AddMargins&gt;b__2(IWpfTextViewMarginProvider mp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object errorSource, Lazy`2 provider, Func`2 getter)
```

In that log entry text, don't miss the text "System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName"

So several places said "delete your temp files", which I did, but I still got the same issues.  :(

Then I took a look at the temp directory, and I saw something weird.  A large amount of (empty) subfolders.

So once I discovered I had a bunch of subfolders in my temp directory, I cleaned up these subfolders.

I found this question:

[How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at command prompt in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965787/how-to-delete-files-subfolders-in-a-specific-directory-at-command-prompt-in-wind)

So I used this code:

I put this code in a .bat file

```
del /q "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

And now my Visual Studio is running ok again.

Wow, go figure.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using windows 10. Try installing VS2015 update 3

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt752379(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN