# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise restarts when i click stop debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC 5 application. Whenever i click stop debugging then visual studio shows an error message saying

> Visual Studio has stopped working

and then it restarts.
Not only with MVC 5 application , i tried a console application also. Even in console application if i click stop debugging , it just restarts. I have tried many options like checking/unchecking certain options in tools>debugging but still the issue persists. Need help in this. Its really irritating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021049/visual-studio-2015-crashes Check this answer

Comment: @mybirthname .. i tried it , still it is crashing