# Visual Studio 2015 Crashes While Moving Tabs or Sorting Internal Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 suddenly crashes while moving any internal window to another place (Toolbox - Solution Explorer), or moving tabs to another window that already has tab in the second monitor.

If moving opened tab to another monitor it working good but once move the second tab beside it, It crashes.

I've uninstalled it and re-installed but the issue still.

I made all commands here [Visual Studio 2015 crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021049/visual-studio-2015-crashes) .. but nothing help

Comment: Does it give you any error message or just shuts down?

Comment: It may be a hardware issue with your computer, try installing on a Virtual and see if the same happens.

Comment: @l0cke A Visual Studio Stop Working message then Debug or Close buttons available

Comment: I am using VS 2012. The problem was solved when I uninstalled the KB4601050 update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Sergey Vlasov .. Thanks a lot .. Fixed after following these steps

- Edit **%InstallRoot%**\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config
- Edit **%LocalAppData%**\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_xxx\devenv.exe.config .. Actually for me after added the following line in the first config file it was added to the second file automatically.
- Append the following text to the **AppContextSwitchOverrides** element’s value attribute:

**;Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.OptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true;Switch.System.Windows.Interop.MouseInput.DoNotOptOutOfMoveToChromedWindowFix=true**

- After restarting VS, you should be able to drag your VS windows around without crashing.

However, based on feedback provided by users who have tested this workaround, it might not resolve the issue on systems where **KB4598299** was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably caused by recent Windows 10 updates: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/recent-windows-10-updates-cause-visual-studio-wpf-app-crashes/

Comment: Actually using Window 8.1