# Visual studio crashing on dock windows

Tags: visual-studio

Since yesterday, my visual studio are crashing everytime i try to dock some windows like toolbar, properties, etc. It freezes for some seconds, then crash without any error message.
Im using vs 2015 pro with update 3 and i cant update to 2017, 2019 or other because thats the license that the company have[image]

How can i fix this?

Edit--
Event viewer as requested

```
Nome do aplicativo com falha: devenv.exe, versão: 14.0.25420.1, carimbo de data/hora: 0x57685d85
Nome do módulo com falha: PresentationCore.ni.dll, versão: 4.8.4320.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x5fc81198
Código de exceção: 0xc000041d
Deslocamento da falha: 0x0076c044
ID do processo com falha: 0x3ee8
Hora de início do aplicativo com falha: 0x01d70b83d00a0053
Caminho do aplicativo com falha: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Caminho do módulo com falha: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\083c71054d41aa078ff981247f747677\PresentationCore.ni.dll
ID do Relatório: 7ed936ef-1132-4070-b1d4-b44716606be0
Nome completo do pacote com falha: 
ID do aplicativo relativo ao pacote com falha:
```

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer for any crash messages? You haven't posted any information so it's impossible to help. As for `I can't update` on the contrary, you can use Visual Studio Community for free. It has the same features as VS Pro. With VS 2015 you can't develop software for .NET Core/.NET 5+ at all.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324052/visual-studio-2015-crashes-while-moving-tabs-or-sorting-internal-windows/

Comment: tks @SergeyVlasov, the accept answer in that question solved the problem

Comment: Same problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and when going to report it I found this similar issue: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unexpected-VS-crash-when-docking-or-spli/1323017

Suggestion there is to update to the latest patched version (I don't know if there is one or there will be one for VS2015 as VS2015 was out of support in 2017) or uninstall KB4598299. There are a lot of other workarounds listed you may want to try if you don't have KB4598299.