# How to delete folders with excluding parent and first child folders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have difficulties creating a batch file or a single Windows command line to delete all files and folders excluding the parent and the first children.

I have for example a folder `Test` having 4 more folders:

- **Test**

  - Folder_1
  - Folder_2
  - Folder_3
  - Folder_4

What I want is to delete everything inside `Folder_1` to `Folder_4`, but keep the folders themselves. (`Test/Folder_1` -> `Test/Folder_4`)

I know how to delete everything inside a parent, but I can't figure it out how to go one layer deeper for running the command in every folder I want to keep:

```
del /q "C:\Temp\Test\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Temp\Test\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Comment: Pushd or cd /d into the folder first and ignore error - you can't remove current dir.

Comment: What about this: `for /D %I in ("C:\Test\*") do pushd "%~I" && (rmdir "%~I" & popd)`

Comment: Since you already know what the child directory is, just delete it and make it again. `for /D %%p in ("C:\Test\*") do (rmdir "%%p" /s /q & mkdir "%%p")`

Comment: @Squashman, just as a note, when deleting and recreating folders, you might lose attibutes or security settings...

Comment: @aschipfl, I guess that could be true if they had a specific ACL set for one of the child folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file can be used to delete all files in `C:\Temp\Test` as well as all files and subfolders in the folders of `C:\Temp\Test`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "BaseFolder=C:\Temp\Test"
if not exist "%BaseFolder%\" goto :EOF

del /A /F /Q "%BaseFolder%\*" >nul 2>nul
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%BaseFolder%" /AD /B 2^>nul') do pushd "%BaseFolder%\%%I" 2>nul && ( rd /Q /S "%BaseFolder%\%%I" 2>nul & popd )

endlocal
```

This batch file deletes also files with hidden and read-only attribute and works also for hidden folders in `C:\Temp\Test`.

Please read answer on [How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at command prompt in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656521/3074564) for a full explanation on how the two command lines deleting files and folders work.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with PowerShell, it might be easier for someone to understand later. Yes, the .bat for loops work. This seems to convey what is being done more directly to me.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()
Get-ChildItem -Path './test' -Recurse -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Verbose "working on $_"
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse
        mkdir $_.FullName | Out-Null
    }
```

If you want to run this from a cmd.exe prompt, put the code above into a file such as delsubs.ps1 and run it with the following.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File delsubs.ps1
```