# How do i delete all sub folders and files inside a parent folder without deleting parent folder

Tags: windows, cmd

I am running the below command on Mac to delete all subfolders and files without deleting the parent folder.

```bash
rm -rf playwright-report/*
```

What will be the equivalent command for a Windows 10 OS?

I tried:

```bash
del /s /q playwright-report
```

But it's only deleting files, not subfolders inside the parent folder.

Comment: ```(pushd playwright-report && (rd /s /q . & popd)) 2>nul```. To find out about each command, open a Command Prompt window, type the command name, followed by `/?`, then press the `[ENTER]` key; e.g. `pushd /?`, `rd /?`. `.` is the relative current directory, `&&` means run the next command only if the previous one completed without error, and `&` means run the next command upon completion of the previous one irrespective of its success or failure. `2>` is a redirection handle for the stdErr stream, in this case I have redirected any such output to the `NUL` device, effectively hiding it.

Comment: @Compo the tooltip for the _Add a comment_ link [also] states: _Avoid answering questions in comments_. I'm curious: why did you not post an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete files/subfolders in a specific directory at the command prompt in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965787/how-to-delete-files-subfolders-in-a-specific-directory-at-the-command-prompt-in)

Comment: @Abra, I didn't post it as an answer because its a duplicate. In fact its almost exactly the same solution as Mofi's answer in the linked duplicate above.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "directory=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\todel"
if exist "%directory%" cd /d "%directory%"
if "%cd%" EQU "%directory%" rd /s /q . 2>nul
```

replace `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\todel` with your folder path `...playwright-report`

Comment: playwright-report is in the root directory of my project and I was running the command while I was inside the project directory.