# How to delete files recursively

Tags: windows, cmd

I have the directory structure /foo/bar/fooBar/.. .  I want to write a Windows command where I can mention the path till foo directory and it deletes all the files and directory recursively in /foo, but it should NOT delete the foo directory.

I have been using `rmdir /q /s [path to foo]` but this command deletes the foo directory as well. Let me know if there is any command(s) to accomplish this.

Comment: what if you cd to /path/to/foo before performing rmdir ?

Comment: del /s *.xml
Works in Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What ever happened to deltree, and what's its replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338895/what-ever-happened-to-deltree-and-whats-its-replacement)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
rd /s /q /path/to/foo
md /path/to/foo
```

Comment: I had a bunch of nested folders and files with some that were read only.  This deleted all of them except the read only, which is what I expected.  This was better than the Windows Server 2003 functionality which would stop the process when it encountered a read only file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```cpp
del /f /s /q DirectoryWhichContainsFilesToDelete/\*
```

This will delete all files in the folder `DirectoryWhichContainsFilesToDelete` without deleting the folder itself.
Have fun :)

Comment: Doesn't delete **directories** inside DirectoryWhichContainsFilesToDelete.

Answer (score 6):

I had been scratching my head on this one as well.  It is easy enough to create a for loop that uses rmdir however it leaves behind folders that have spaces in the long names.  It is possible to manipulate a dir list and get the 8.3 filenames however here is a much simpler solution.

Create an empty folder then;

```
robocopy \empty_folder \folder_with_sub_folders /PURGE
```

All subfolders & files will be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

```
del X /f /s /q 
rd X /s /q
```

this WILL remove the ROOt directory though. make it again with

```
 md X
```

or make a copy of it first.

otherwise you'll have to do batch funkiness

```
 dir X /ad /b
```

will give you a list of the immediate subdirectories of X. you can work out the rest

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a simple command to delete all files in a directory recursively but leaving the directory structure unchanged. So, maybe this could be interesting ;)

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /B /S /A:-DH') do @del /F /Q /A:H "%i"
```

The command 'dir /B /S /A:-D' lists only files (/A:-D) in current directory recursively (/S) without 'dir' summary report (/B). The 'for' loops through each full line (/delims=) and executes the delete command, forced and quiet. I additionally used the hidden flag (/H) both for listing and deletion for some mysterious (e.g. thumbs.db) files.

Comment: this worked for me too, I had to delete certain files matching a wildcard recursively in all sub-folders, so I used `for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /a-d /s "P:\Systems\A.L.P.S\~$PS*"') do @del /F /Q /A:H "%i"`and wow, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

deltree /foo/* should work fine.

Comment: I am unfortunate enough not to have deltree command on Windows XP

Comment: Then you should stick with @Ferruccio's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in a batch file in the past.  It uses a for loop to navigate the directory structure.

Here I remove the cvs sub directories off of a tree, needed when copying from one branch to another.

```
@echo off
if /I exist CVS. rd CVS /s /q >nul
for /F %%z in ('dir cvs /ad /s /b') do echo %%z && rd /s /q %%z
echo Batchfile %0 is complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Powershell:

```
powershell -Command "Remove-Item '\foo\*' -Recurse -Force"
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent deleting of the foo directory try change directory to foo prior to the delete such as:

cd c:\foo
rd /s /q c:\foo

This will delete all the files and folders under foo but NOT foo. An error message will be displayed as follow "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."